# How do I get SQL*Plus to create views / tables with a blank line in the middle of the create statement?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I wish to create some views using SQL*Plus via script, but seem to hit a problem if a developer has placed a blank line mid statement. 
The following statement works fine in TOAD / PL/SQL developer etc, but fails in SQL*Plus. 
(This is usually scripted, but entering it manually gives exactly the same error)

Can anyone tell me why / how to stop it?

```
CREATE VIEW bob
AS
SELECT *

FROM DUAL;
```

With SQL*Plus output

```
SQL> CREATE VIEW bob
  2  AS
  3  SELECT *
  4
SQL> FROM DUAL;
SP2-0042: unknown command "FROM DUAL" - rest of line ignored.
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You would use the `SET SQLBLANKLINES` command:

```
SQL> SET SQLBLANKLINES on
SQL>
SQL> CREATE VIEW bob
  2  AS
  3  SELECT *
  4  
  5  FROM DUAL;

View created
```

Comment: @Jonathan - It's certainly not the strangest hoop Oracle has made me jump through!

Comment: +1 I've worked with Oracle and SQL Plus for nearly 2 decades, and didn't know that one!

Comment: +1, had never heard of it. It is apparently a quirk of SQL*Plus, as for example PL/SQL Developer behaves quite nicely with the OP's example.

Answer (score 0):

The SQLBLANKLINES setting, a new feature in Version 8.1 of SQL*Plus, allows SQL statements to contain embedded blank lines.

ON - Turns on the feature and allows you to enter a SQL statement with an embedded blank line.

OFF - Turns off this feature. This is the default setting and doesn't allow a SQL statement to have embedded blank lines.